# Is setPosition(1, 2) a lot faster than setPosition(new Point(1, 2))

Tags: java, optimization

Two method implementations:

> public void setPosiotion(int x, int y) {
>      //do nothing
>   }
>
> public void setPosiotion(Point point) {
>      //do nothing
>   }

What if I had to call setPosition() 1 billion times, would the method that doesn't require to create a new Point work noticeably faster?

Comment: depends on wether or not "setPostition(int x, int y){ this.setPosition(new Point(x, y)); }" is the implementation of the first method.  Which class are you talking about, here?

Comment: What happened when you profiled it?

Comment: From my understanding, object creation consumes time, but I think it is unnoticeable, even if you create it billion times. But since Java is object oriented, in my opinion working with objects is much more comfortable. About the question if it is a lot faster, I would recommend profiling as @AndrewThompson mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

It could make a small difference, but its likely to be less than it time it takes you to write the longer expression.  Sometimes your time and your efficiency is more important.

Even more important than the time it takes to write, is the time spent maintaining the code which can be 3x the time taken to develop it.  This suggests maintainability should be your main concern.

In short; write simple, clearly understood code and it will often perform well and be the most effective in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

> What if I had to call setPosition() 1 billion times, would the method that doesn't require to create a new Point work noticeably faster?

It depends what the `setPosition` method does.

- If the method simply uses the `x` and `y` values from the `Point` then it is probably faster not to create / pass a `Point` object.
- If the method immediately creates a `Point` to hold the `x` and `y` values that you passed, then creating the `Point` yourself *could* be faster.

This is complicated by the fact the latest JVMs could use escape analysis to deduce that the `Point` object doesn't need to be created as a heap object.  And on the flip side, it depends how many levels of method call (etcetera) the `x` and `y` values need to be passed through.

In short, it is hard to predict.

---

Finally, your assumption that `setPosition` will be called a billion times is suspect ... unless you've actually profiled the application.  And even if it is valid, these calls might *still* make an insignificant contribution to the overall application execution time.

Profile first, and *then* optimize.